# Are there any Sunni hadith similar to this Shia hadith about non muslims?

Tags: hadith, shia-sunni

I saw this hadith among Shia collection and don't recall reading similar themes or events among the sunni literature. Anyone know any hadith (besides Bukhari 3883) that are similar or have similar themes?

“Amongst the Banī Isrā’īl (Children of Isrā’il) there was a believer whose neighbour was an unbeliever. That unbeliever would always show kindness and good conduct towards his believing neighbour. When this unbeliever died, God made for him a house out of a type of mud which shielded him from the heat of the fire, and his sustenance would be given to him from outside his own environment, which was of fire. He was told, ‘This is because of your kindness and good conduct towards your believing neighbour.’”

Jazakallah

Comment: Please consider asking one question per post, and if possible provide the Arabic text of the ahadith. I can recognize the content of last hadith: the person who stole from the pilgrims with a stick is recorded in [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:904c) the one about the woman who killed a cat in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3318) and the one about the man who gave water to a dog in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:173). Note that the last one is not a non-Muslim.

Comment: Secondly note that it is not possible for a disbeliever to enter paradise, and it is not possible for any hadith to say that since it would contradict the Quran. However within Hellfire it is possible that some disbelievers will have lesser punishment than others. And this is what the first two ahadith you have mentioned say, and this also has examples within Sunni ahadith such as [Bukhari 3883](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3883)

Comment: @UmH Jazakallah, I updated the question. Yes, ideally I'm looking for other Hadith similar to 3883 if there are